# i can't add new attribute in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a project in node and express and mongoose, i have a controller for return all orders of the logued client, when I query the database i want see the status of each order and depending on the state, add the availableStatus field to null or to the available states.
this is my controller:

```
const getOrdersByUser = async ( req = request, res = response) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.user;
        const orders = await Orders.find({ customer: id })
            .populate('status', 'name')
            .populate('account')
            .populate('package');

        if ( !orders ) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                ok: false,
                data: ['El usuario no tiene ordenes registradas!']
            })
        }

        const requestCancellation = await OrderStatus.findOne({ name: 'Solicitud de cancelación.'});
        
        orders.forEach(element => {
            if ( element.status.name === 'Carga en proceso.' || element.status.name === 'Carga en proceso(Demoras).') {
                console.log('entra aqui');
                element.availableStates = [requestCancellation]
            } else {
                element.availableStates = [null];
            }
        });

        console.log(orders[0].availableStates);
        console.log(orders);

        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            data: orders
        })

    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            data: [error.message]
        })
    }

}
```

This is a response for console:

```
Server runing in port: 3005
Database Connected
entra aqui
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65edfd1359cb75c67bdd4738'),
    name: 'Solicitud de cancelación.',
    description: 'El usuario desea cancelar la recarga, el administrador debe aprobar o no la cancelación.'
  }
]
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65ede332942db9ca3807554c'),
    orden_number: 'Play',
    customer: new ObjectId('65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7'),
    history: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    status: {
      _id: new ObjectId('65e86316940764700aa3a7b3'),
      name: 'Carga en proceso.'
    },
    account: {
      _id: new ObjectId('65cfc9279892a31557af028e'),
      game: new ObjectId('65ca524190a477fd6ec88b81'),
      access: 'Facebook',
      nickname: 'Prueba2',
      email: 'b2@facebook.com',
      user: new ObjectId('65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7'),
      __v: 0
    },
    secure_codes: '111111 22222222 333333',
    package: {
      _id: new ObjectId('657b4f7815b946f9d46797cd'),
      amount: '7400'
    },
    comments: 'Se validara si el pago se realizo correctamente',
    create_at: 2024-03-10T16:43:30.862Z,
    update_at: 2024-03-12T04:03:47.849Z,
    __v: 1
  }
]
```

You can see that when I print the 'availableStatus' of the order in position 0, it shows me the content, but when I print the complete 'orders' object the 'availableStatus' attribute is not displayed in any of the orders.
Likewise, when I make the request, the response does not bring 'availableStatus'

this is my response in postman from backend

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "65ede332942db9ca3807554c",
            "orden_number": "Play",
            "customer": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7",
            "history": [
                {
                    "status": "65e495b6e66f7303fe97f237",
                    "name_status": "Pago en Verificación",
                    "update_at": "2024-03-10T16:43:30.756Z",
                    "updater": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7"
                },
                {
                    "status": "65e86316940764700aa3a7b3",
                    "name_status": "Carga en proceso.",
                    "update_at": "2024-03-12T04:03:47.847Z",
                    "updater": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7"
                }
            ],
            "status": {
                "_id": "65e86316940764700aa3a7b3",
                "name": "Carga en proceso."
            },
            "account": {
                "_id": "65cfc9279892a31557af028e",
                "game": "65ca524190a477fd6ec88b81",
                "access": "Facebook",
                "nickname": "Prueba2",
                "email": "b2@facebook.com",
                "user": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "secure_codes": "111111 22222222 333333",
            "package": {
                "_id": "657b4f7815b946f9d46797cd",
                "amount": "7400"
            },
            "comments": "Se validara si el pago se realizo correctamente",
            "create_at": "2024-03-10T16:43:30.862Z",
            "update_at": "2024-03-12T04:03:47.849Z",
            "__v": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "65f199ccd9964955954877c4",
            "orden_number": "Play",
            "customer": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7",
            "history": [
                {
                    "status": "65e495b6e66f7303fe97f237",
                    "name_status": "Pago en Verificación.",
                    "update_at": "2024-03-13T12:19:23.981Z",
                    "updater": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7"
                }
            ],
            "status": {
                "_id": "65e495b6e66f7303fe97f237",
                "name": "Pago en Verificación."
            },
            "account": {
                "_id": "65cae9382a687ed2764e1a97",
                "game": "65ca524190a477fd6ec88b81",
                "access": "Activision",
                "nickname": "Clyde",
                "email": "a@gmail.com",
                "user": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "secure_codes": null,
            "package": {
                "_id": "657b4f7815b946f9d46797cd",
                "amount": "7400"
            },
            "comments": "Se validara si el pago se realizo correctamente",
            "create_at": "2024-03-13T12:19:24.081Z",
            "update_at": "2024-03-13T12:19:24.081Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "65f1b1b58d54976da39f5f38",
            "orden_number": "Play",
            "customer": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7",
            "history": [
                {
                    "status": "65e495b6e66f7303fe97f237",
                    "name_status": "Pago en Verificación.",
                    "update_at": "2024-03-13T14:01:25.679Z",
                    "updater": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7"
                }
            ],
            "status": {
                "_id": "65e495b6e66f7303fe97f237",
                "name": "Pago en Verificación."
            },
            "account": {
                "_id": "65cae9382a687ed2764e1a97",
                "game": "65ca524190a477fd6ec88b81",
                "access": "Activision",
                "nickname": "Clyde",
                "email": "a@gmail.com",
                "user": "65cadbd69610d8bccb1168c7",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "secure_codes": null,
            "package": {
                "_id": "657b4f7815b946f9d46797cd",
                "amount": "7400"
            },
            "comments": "Se validara si el pago se realizo correctamente",
            "create_at": "2024-03-13T14:01:25.780Z",
            "update_at": "2024-03-13T14:01:25.780Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

really i don't understand what happend with the attribute 'availableStatus', why when i print availableStatus in console of a specify order this exist, but when i print the complet information of an order the attribute 'availableStatus' not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it seems like a Mongoose problem.

When you fetch/get data from the Database through the Mongoose, it's not returned the **plain JavaScript Object**; they are instances of the Mongoose **Document** class. This class has its own behavior on parse its data to object or etc.

When you assign a property to this object (in this case is ***element.availableStates***), it doesn't become a part of the **Document**'s data but a JavaScript object property (this is why you can access it via `orders[0].availableStates`). So, when it comes to `console.log(orders)`, the truly behavior is it converts its own data (**Document**) and shows them up. That why you can't see the data after modified it.

How to fix this:

1. Add the `availableStates` property to the **Schema**
2. Convert the **Document** --> the **plain JavaScipt object**

**Example 1**: Using forEach()

```js
orders.forEach(element => {
  element = element.toObject()
  if ( element.status.name === 'A' || element.status.name === 'B') {
    element.availableStates = [requestCancellation]
  } else {
    element.availableStates = [null];
  }
});
```

**Example 2**: Using map()

```js
const modifiedOrders = orders.map(order => {
  const plainOrder = order.toObject()
  if ( plainOrder.status.name === 'A' || plainOrder.status.name === 'B') {
    plainOrder.availableStates = [requestCancellation]
  } else {
    plainOrder.availableStates = [null];
  }
  return plainOrder;
});
```

Comment: i try with map and forEach but the resolve is same, the other solution you propose is add 'availableStates' to model of Orders?

Comment: I just did it and it works totally fine with me, you can try other solution as well!